# How to print date label once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a chat application using `vueJs` and I would like to display date labels just like whats app.

Messages are received in following format on client side

```
{

    {
        author: 21,
        created_at: "12:09 pm",
        data: "chat message",
        message_group: "today",
        type: "text" 
    },
    {
        author: 22,
        created_at: "11:30 pm",
        data: "chat message 2",
        message_group: "today",
        type: "text"
    },
    {
        author: 22,
        created_at: "11:29 pm",
        data: "chat message 3",
        message_group: "yesterday",
        type: "text"
    }
}
```

How do I print messages in following format.

```
Yesterday
    Chat Message 3
Today
    Chat Message 2
    Chat Message
```

How can I do it without grouping the array?

Thank you

Comment: When receive new message, you can push them directly to the merged array.
`mergedMessaged[newMessage.message_group].push(newMessage)`

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it in the comment up there so putting it as an answer.

You can have a **computed property** or **getter** (vuex) to get the day labels without grouping as below

```
// Do your sorting first
computed: {
  dayLabels() {
    return a.reduce((acc, message) => {
      if (!acc.includes(message.message_group)) {
          acc.push(message.message_group);  
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
}
```

Comment: I could get the labels or send labels from server side but how do I print `html` on `vue` side. I need to sort the data and inject the labels. Is there a way to do that without grouping?

Comment: You can do the above to get the distinct list of day labels. then you can use it in your template. eg: `<label v-for="dayLabel in dayLabels">{{dayLabel}}</label>`

Comment: I am still a bit confused how that could work. Can you please create an example for me? I am confused that how to inject them when date of the message changes?

Comment: See if this one does what you want. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-gpwkm . Vue will detect changes in messages array and compute the dayLabels accordingly.

Comment: it adds labels on the top. I want to make it like whats app. A label and then all messages of that day and then next day's label if any message on that day and so on.